# How to show only thumbnails images?

Tags: php, image, loops, foreach

I've some images in a **upload** directory and in the directory there is both type of images(Thumbnail & Original Images) uploaded and I just want to show only thumbnails images but unable to hide original images.

Here is the example of uploaded image files

**Original File : 5857bf4b74dcb.jpg**

**Thumbnail File : thumb_5857bf4b74dcb.jpg**

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir("uploads/")) {
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { ?>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="well well-sm text-center">
<img src="<?php echo $fd.'uploads/'.$_GET['f'].'/'.$entry; ?>" alt="<?php echo str_replace(" .jpg ", " ", $entry); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
</div>
</div>        
<?php } } closedir($handle); }
```

Comment: If you have not prefixed or suffixed the thumbnails with a special marker (e.q. `thumb_*.jpg`), there is no way you can distinguish either. Best bet is to do that or separate them 'physically' by putting the thumb in an other folder...

Comment: Yes I added  prefix **thumb_**

Comment: `echo $fd.'uploads/'.$_GET['f']` - your code is prone to XSS-attacks. **never** trust user input.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann you're right, but let him focus on this first... ;)

Comment: @Raphioly-San it's never too early to care about safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check filename has `thumb_` or not by using [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) or [`strrpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php).

Try

```
if ($handle = opendir("uploads/"))
{
  while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
  {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..")
      {
        if( stristr($entry, 'thumb_'))
        {

      ?>
  <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="well well-sm text-center">
  <img src="<?php echo $fd.'uploads/'.$_GET['f'].'/'.$entry; ?>" alt="<?php echo str_replace(" .jpg ", " ", $entry); ?>" class="img-thumbnail" />
  </div>
  </div>        
  <?php
        }
    }
  }
  closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: @PawanMall please mark tick on my answer, if you found it useful for you :)